# Scatter plot: Using different colour for different data set

Tags: arrays, matlab, plot, 3d, scatter-plot

I have 3 Nx1 arrays, say X,Y,Z. I'd like to create a 3D plot such that each of the arrays I can assign different colours to improve the visibility of points. My main objective now is to change only the colour of array Z, such that elements of array X and Y have different colours as that of elements of Z .

I tried `scatter3` function and `gscatter` MATLAB functions, but not able to achieve what I desire.

[image: desired 3D plot]

If we see the Vertical axis in image (Z axis), the colour of points is varying from Blue to Orange/Yellow. I want to set the colour of all these Z points as Red. Rest, all the colours of X and Y points remain same

Comment: Please be a little more descriptive about why `scatter3` and `gscatter` don't work.

Comment: Also please add a reproducible example

Comment: @Suever, I couldn't understand the Grouping in gscatter.

Comment: Can you please add an image that shows what you want?

Comment: @zeeMonkeez I have added the image.

Comment: Every point is defined by its x,y,z coordinates. Unless you want each point to be represented by 3 different color components, the question does not make sense. Please show us an image of what you actually want, not how the image you have is not sufficient...

Comment: This worked for me.

group = Z(:,1);
gscatter(X(:,1),Y(:,1),group, 'gr', 'xo');

This makes the X and Y points as green and Z as red in the 3D Plane

Answer (score 0):

[`scatter(x, y, a, c)`](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colorspec.html) takes arguments `x` and `y`, and then `a` for size, and `c` for colour. `a` can either be a single scalar, or a vector with a size for each `(x,y)` point. `c` can be an [RGB triplet](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colorspec.html), or a vector, the same size as `x` and `y`. For example:

```
x = 1:4;
scatter(x, x, 10*x, x);
```

results in

[image: Example]

[`scatter3(x,y,z,s,c)`](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html) is similar, so in your case, perhaps

```
scatter3(X,Y,Z,[],Z)
```

will result in your data having a different colour determined by its z value.

One little example which I think is what you're looking for:

```
X = rand(100,1);
Y = rand(100,1);
Z = rand(100,1);

scatter3(X,Y,Z,[],Z)
```

Produces:

[image]

Comment: This much I'm able to do. I want to separate colours for each X, Y and Z.

Comment: @user3098378 You mean you want a different colour for every point in your scatter plot?

Comment: I want that all the points in X have say Red colour, all points in Y have say Green colour, and similarly all points in Z have say Blue colour.

Comment: @user3098378 So you want a one dimensional scatter plot? As in `scatter(zeros(N,1),X,[],'r'); scatter(zeros(N,1),Y,[],'g'); scatter(zeros(N,1),Z,[],'b')`?

Comment: No, I want a 3D scatter plot. The 3D graph you displayed is perfect. What I want is: say all x values have same red colour, all y values have same blue colour and so on. And these different coloured x,y,z plotted in 3D together.

Comment: @user3098378 But I thought that the values in your x array are the x values for all of your points?

Comment: X, Y, and Z are separate arrays of same size 7024x1. I want to plot them together, as in scatter3, exactly the way you plotted above, considering X array as X values, Y array as Y values for the plot and so on. However, I want that points of X values should have same colour say Red,  points of Y values should have same colour say Green and so on.

Comment: @user3098378 "However, I want that points of X values should have same colour say Red" This is all the points. All of the points rely on X,Y, and Z arrays for information, so you cannot colour them separately.

Comment: Can we use gscatter for this purpose? Help me.

Comment: @user3098378 I don't think you understand what you are asking for---it's not possible. Can you draw a picture maybe to explain what you are trying to describe?

Comment: This worked for me.
       
group = Z(:,1);
gscatter(X(:,1),Y(:,1),group, 'gr', 'xo');      

This makes the X and Y points as green and Z as red in the 3D Plane

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer by trying different MATLAB functions.

I used the `gscatter` function. As I had to colour all the Z points(consider 'Z' array as the 3rd data set) as Red and rest X and Y data set (the other 2 data set) as green or other colour, I used the following code:

```
group = Z(:,1); 
gscatter(X(:,1),Y(:,1),group, 'gr', 'xo');
```

It creates a 2D plot but serves my purpose.

The Image is made of 3 data sets, but the first 2 data sets are intentionally combined (in Green Cross) and 3rd data set is kept Red, to visualize the relation of 3rd data set with 1st and 2nd data sets combined.

[Click here for Image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5jn2.jpg)